# Conexion de programas en una red privada!

Tags: servidor

Buenas chicos, eh creado un programa de escritorio que sera utilizado en varios equipos y se conectaran a una base de datos que esta alojada en un servidor en otro equipo, alguien sabe como poner la direccion ip del equipo en donde esta elservidor estatica, osea para que nunca cambie, o conocen alguna forma de poder ponerle un nombre al servidor para que los programas siempre puedan conectarse??

Comment: Si estas usando Windows, puede usar el nombre del equipo en vez de la dirección IP, esto funcionara siempre y cuando todos los equipos se encuentre en el mismo segmento de RED que el servidor.

Comment: sabes donde cambio la ip por el nombre del equipo?

Comment: Pues en donde estés haciendo tu programa, me imagino que tienes alguna cadena de conexión.

Comment: eh probado desde el navegador y no me deja. Con la ip de mi equipo si puedo ver el servidor. lo que quisiera hacer es pornerle un nombre al servidor para que cuando se reinicie el equipo pueda seguir ingresando y no tener que fijarme la ip de nuevo, ya que desde los programas no podria hacer eso.